# Check if selects tags has the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have 4 selects with same class (no ID), and I want when I choose an option to disable it in the other selects,

```
<select name="column_type[]" class="form-control column_type">
 <option value="none">Ne pas Importer</option>
 <option value="mobile">Mobile</option><option value="mail">Email
 </option><option value="lname">Nom</option>
</select>
....
```

So plz if someone has any idea I will be very appreciative.

Comment: please post your jquery code here too

Comment: same class and same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have understood as your question,when you select a option in a `select` tags it disables all the other `select` tags:

**JS**:

```
function onOptionChange(elem){
     var selects=document.getElementsByClassName("form-control column_type");
     for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
       if(selects[i]!=elem)
         selects[i].options[elem.selectedIndex].disabled=true;
    }
```

**HTML**:

```
<select name="column_type[]" class="form-control column_type" onChange="return onOptionChange(this)">
  <option value="none">Ne pas Importer</option>
  <option value="mobile">Mobile</option><option value="mail">Email</option>
  <option value="lname">Nom</option>
</select>
```

If that's not what you want, I'll edit the answer

Comment: thnx for your answer, but what i want is when i select an option this option must disable in other selects, not disable the others select

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery prop() to disable:

```js
$(function() {
  var column_type = $('.column_type');
  column_type.on('change', function() {
    var cur = $(this);
    $.each(column_type, function(_, dd) {
      dd = $(dd);
      if (cur != dd) {
        dd.find('option').eq(cur.prop('selectedIndex')).prop('disabled', true);
      }
    })
  }).eq(0).trigger('change');// fire event on page load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="column_type[]" class="form-control column_type">
  <option value="none">Ne pas Importer</option>
  <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
  <option value="mail">Email
  </option>
  <option value="lname">Nom</option>
</select>
<select name="column_type[]" class="form-control column_type">
  <option value="none">Ne pas Importer</option>
  <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
  <option value="mail">Email
  </option>
  <option value="lname">Nom</option>
</select>
<select name="column_type[]" class="form-control column_type">
  <option value="none">Ne pas Importer</option>
  <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
  <option value="mail">Email
  </option>
  <option value="lname">Nom</option>
</select>
<select name="column_type[]" class="form-control column_type">
  <option value="none">Ne pas Importer</option>
  <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
  <option value="mail">Email
  </option>
  <option value="lname">Nom</option>
</select>
```